# Where should i place helper method for rspec test in Rails6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have helper method for rspec test like this :
<bla_bla_helper.rb>

```
Module blabla
  def bla
  end
end
```

Where should i place this module?
This module is only for rspec test.

Past version of Rails used `spec/support` directory, should i use this directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RSpec you use `spec/support` to place the helpers, matchers, shared contexts etc that your specs need. This path is added to the load path so you can simply do `require 'foo'` in your specs to require `spec/support/foo.rb`.

Some projects use a glob in `spec/spec_helper.rb` to require all the files in the `spec/support` directory.

This is just an RSpec convention that has nothing to do with Rails, so the practice isn't going to change with Rails versions.

Answer (score 1):

I usually place mine inside `spec/support/helpers` and include it in the configuration via `rails_helper`.

Here's an example of including the devise API auth helper that I am using for my application.

`config.include DeviseApiAuthHelper, type: :controller`

Comment: Is type of helper necessary keyword?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can continue using spec/support directory.